# Enabling dual boot in grub: debian and graphical *BSD

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, bsd

After installing `*BSD` to unallocated disk space, my computer didn't boot properly any more. With choosing a boot image, my screen froze. So I ran the rescue mode of a debian install medium and reinstalled the MBR (Master Boot Record). Now, GRUB acts as if debian was the only system on the drive.

I tried updating GRUB from GNU/Linux, which gave me the following:

`$ sudo LC_ALL=C update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background image: .background_cache.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-2-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-2-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-1-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-1-amd64
Found memdisk: /memdisk
Imagepath /boot/images not found
done`

I take any `*BSD` which has a GUI by default because [TrueOS](https://www.trueos.org) now is deprecated.
How do I have to modify the file telling GRUB which OSes there are available? Which file is it (in which directory)?

Comment: i think that `update-grub` command does it  .......  https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/grub-legacy/update-grub.8.en.html